# Restricting XML element values based on other values in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-1.1

I am creating a schema in XSD 1.1 for crossword puzzles. One of my elements is `<dimensions>`. Example:

```
<xs:element name="dimensions">
    <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="\d+x\d+"/>
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
 </xs:element>
```

The resulting XML would look like `<dimensions>21x21</dimensions>`, meaning that the puzzle grid is 21 squares by 21 squares.

I also have a `<cell>` element for every square in the puzzle. So for a puzzle with dimensions of 21x21, I would have 441 instances of `<cell>`. Each `<cell`> has a `<coordinates>` element describing its position in the grid:

```
<xs:element name="cell">  
    <xs:complexType>  
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="coordinates">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:pattern value="\d+,\d+"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

So the position of the square in the bottom left corner of the grid would be represented by `<coordinates>21,1</coordinates>`, indicating that it is in the 21st row, 1st column.

I want to do the following:

1. Require that there is one `<cell>` for every square, based on the `<dimensions>`. For instance, if the dimensions are 21x21, there must be 441 instances of `<cell>`--no more, no fewer.
2. Require that the `<coordinates>` for each `<cell>` are unique and fall within the parameters of the `<dimensions`. In other words, for a 21x21 grid, each axis of the coordinates must be represented by a number between 1 and 21, and each of the 441 combinations can only be used once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need XSD 1.1; use an assertion.  Or you will need to parameterize your schema (and probably reorganize your XML a bit) to enforce the constraint in a different way (e.g. by having the schema require exactly 21 rows, each with exactly 21 cells).

Comment: I am using XSD 1.1, but I can't parameterize the schema to require exactly 21 rows/cells, because it needs to accommodate puzzles with different sized grids (e.g., 15x15).  So how would I write an assertion that can make the parameters dependent on the dimensions?

Comment: If you MUST use exactly the same schema for all puzzles, then of course parameterizing it won't work.  But needing to accommodate puzzles of different sizes is a reason to parameterize it, not a reason you cannot do so.  On how to use assertions -- what have you tried so far?

Comment: I guess I could create a set of schemas for common grid types and dimensions, but that's probably outside the scope of this project, which is for school; I'm trying to create a TEI-derived (TEI-inspired?) schema for encoding unconventional texts with lots of structure, like word puzzles. I barely understand assertions (I just learned what they are yesterday when I posted this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37127791/control-element-cardinality-based-on-an-attribute-enumeration-in-xsd), so I haven't attempted one yet.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, assertions could be used, but **an XML design change would be better...**

The information you would place in `dimensions` is implied by the structure of your `cell` elements and can be *derived automatically* rather than allowed to be *set arbitrarily* and then have to be validated independently.

A similar argument applies to `coordinates`.

(Note also that even if you did wish to represent coordinates explicitly, it'd be better to use separate elements, or better yet, attributes, for each coordinate.)

Comment: For a variety of reasons, including enforcement of correct data entry, I DO want to represent `coordinates` explicitly. So if I create a coordinate attribute for each `cell`, or two attributes (one for each axis), do I still have to use an assertion? Or is there another way?

Comment: Data entry validation is better performed before data hits XML, and separate attributes obviously do not address your validation concerns.  Note that I've already shown you an example of [how to use XSD 1.1 assertions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37129215/290085).  I won't do so again here, and, frankly, (1) You don't need assertions here if you fix your design, and (2) if you insist that you want them, you ought to take a stab at them yourself after having already been shown how to use them.

Comment: I understand your comment about data entry validation being better performed before data hits XML; that's what I was getting at when I asked for a way to control the number of `cells` and the values of the `coordinates`, to take it out of the hands of the person creating the XML. So I'm not asking for an assertion, I just don't understand whether it's possible to "fix my design" in such a way that the coordinates are explicit _without_ using an assertion, and if so, what that would entail.